# SVG word animation

Tags: svg

I have a mobile application that involves moving of text in a marquee way. I used css3 animation and it looks laggy on the mobile. I choose to use svg as an animation. How can I implement a marquee animation in a svg. I am new in this.

Comment: It's unlikely SVG will perform any differently than css3 animation.

Comment: Robert Longson thanks for the reply, but can I use svg to perform a marquee effect on text?

Comment: You'd do it via SMIL. The more detail you supply in the question, the more guidance I can provide.

Comment: Then you need a book and not a Q&A service.

Comment: Not every question has a simple answer. Your question is like "I've built a flat, how do I build a riverboat that resembles my flat. You've not told us anything about the flat so we can't tell you much about how to build the riverboat you want. Even if we did the answer would be at a pretty high level.

Comment: Add more detail to your question.  If you have a working CSS version, then include that so we can see what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple animation with scrolling text. Hopefully this will get you started.

There are numerous tutorials on the web on how to do SVG animation. You could also read the SVG specification if you want more information.

Note that SMIL animation like this (SMIL is animation that uses the `<animate>` tag) does not work in IE.  But you could use a library like FakeSmile if you need to support IE.

```html
<svg width="500" height="100">
  <text x="0" y="80" font-size="80">Here is some scrolling text
    <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="x" 
         values="520;-880;520" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </text>
</svg>
```